# Can't change screens with conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I made a login screen for my app, and another navigator for the rest of the app. I want to user to be send to the loginscreen when he's not signed in (tokens). Now I use conditional rendering to return the right window. But This has as a downside, that when the screen is loaded, it can't be changed (as far as I know). For example the login button works, I log in, but it doesn't change the screen...

```js
 const [isSignedIn, setSignedIn] = useState();

return (
    <AuthStack.Navigator>
        {isSignedIn? (
              <AuthStack.Screen name="Tabs" component={Tabs} options={{headerShown : false}}/>
            ) : (
               <>
                  <AuthStack.Screen
                      name = "LoginScreen"
                      component={LoginScreen}
                      options={{
                        title: 'Log In',
                        animationTypeForReplace: isSignedIn ? 'pop' : 'push',
                      }}
                  />
                  <AuthStack.Screen
                    name = "ForgotPassword"
                    component={ForgotPasswordScreen}
                    options={{
                    title: 'ForgotPassword',
                  },
                    animationTypeForReplace: isSignedIn ? 'pop' : 'push',
                  }}
                />
             </>
        )
        }
    </AuthStack.Navigator>

  );
```

I have a logIn function and a log out function, but they don't change teh screens. Does somebody have an idea how to switch between those screens?

Answer (score 0):

**If you are using React Navigation below is the description on the site. I think you should check is your state changing.**

*It's important to note that when using such a setup, you don't manually navigate to the Home screen by calling navigation.navigate('Home') or any other method. React Navigation will automatically navigate to the correct screen when isSignedIn changes - Home screen when isSignedIn becomes true, and to SignIn screen when isSignedIn becomes false. You'll get an error if you attempt to navigate manually.*

Comment: I think I see what you mean, the isSigned in boolean determines which screen is rendered, so when this boolean changes, it should change the screen (if I'm correct?). This leads me to another problem, how can I change  this boolean in another screen, in this case the LoginScreen?

Comment: You can use global state management ( Redux , Context API). This is a great authentication flow document. It can be helpful.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/